# Можно ли как-то обойти "infinite recursive call", чтобы его не было

Tags: массивы, функции, golang, рекурсия, append

## в 14 строке пишет "infinite recursive call"

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func append([]int) []int{
    var num int
    list := []int{}
    fmt.Scan(&num)
    list2 := append(list) // вот тут пишет "infinite recursive call"
    return list2

}

func main() {
    lis2t := []int{}
    value := append(lis2t)
    fmt.Println(value)

}
```

нужно чтоб не писал в 14 строке "infinite recursive call")

Comment: А что по-вашему должен делать представленный код?  В функции `append` нет выхода из рекурсии, а указан только рекурсивный вызов самой себя.

Comment: да я понял, так а как поменять код чтоб выйти из рекурсии не пойму

Comment: @F1n4ikuLL, "я знаю, как класть пирожки в холодильник, но как их не класть?"

Answer (score 1):

*Я беру глыбу мрамора и отсекаю от нее все лишнее (© Микельанджело Буанаротти)*
... а рекурсию заменяю на итерацию.

```go
func append([]int) []int{
    var num int
    var err error
    for err == nil {
        _, err = fmt.Scan(&num)
    }
    return nil
}
```

В случае, если вам не нужно выходить из функции, не проверяйте ошибку ;)

Серьезно. Опишите, что вы хотите получить. Большая вероятность, что правильно задав вопрос, вы сами найдете ответ.

PS
Использовать имя встроенной функции `append` в качестве имени пользовательской функции - плохая идея.